# JSON array - Possibility of multiple valid answers?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm quite new to JSON and javascript. I'm a teacher and currently developing an app to teach students. The questions I make sometimes have a single valid answer, but sometimes they have multiple correct answers. An example of one of them is in the following code:

```
{
  "q":"3. What does it say?",
  "au":"audio/3.mp3",
  "answr1":"I am American",
  "answr2":"I am America",
  "canswer":"I am American",
  "answrfeedback":"Remember that country and nationality are different things. ",
  "answrType":"8"
},
```

As you can see, canswr is the correct answer. If a student were to answer this question with a text input, two answers would be valid:

1. The already specified answer in the JSON object: canswer = I am American
2. An answer that is not specified in the object: I'm American

My question then is... does JSON count with an OR possibility within the txt file?
If not, which do you think would be the way to go about this little problem?

Thanks!

Comment: JSON doesn't count anything.

Comment: @user2355171: JSON is just a format for storing (and sending) data.

Comment: JSON is just a data-interchange format. You will need the logic in your javascript to store the count of correct answers that a student selects. Can you also post the javascript/ HTML markup snippet, if possible, that consumes this JSON? It might give some more clarity on what the actual issue is...

Answer (score 3):

JSON does support arrays. I would change the format of your JSON to the following schema:

```
{
    "question": "1. Question text",
    "audio": "path/to/audio.mp3",
    "answers": [{
        "text": "Answer 1",
        "correct": true,
    }, {
        "text": "Answer 2",
        "correct": false
    }]
}
```

This way you can have multiple correct answers (i.e. the ones with the `correct` field set to `true`).

Comment: I tend to agree that storing `correct` as an attribute of the answer is the right direction for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Since JSON is a key value store, each key has one associated value. However--a JSON array can store all sorts of data--in fact the "value" in a key value store could be an array as well, which means you can have multiple values attached to a single key. Depending on how you're validating the correct answer to this question, though, there are many ways you could go about this. Maybe providing your markup or your actual script would be helpful for people to go about answering your question!

EDIT: added example.

For instance, with your current setup, you could do this:

```
{
    "q": "3. What does it say?",
    "au": "audio/3.mp3",
    "answr1": "I am American",
    "answr2": "I am America",
    "canswer": ["I am american","I'm American"],
    "answrfeedback": "Remember that country and nationality are different things. ",
    "answrType": "8"
}
```

Then, loop over the values in "canswer". However this might not be the ideal solution depending again, on how you plan on accessing the data.

Comment: I'm aware that it would be best to post the js script but I didn't do so because the school I'm working for provided part of it and I'm not sure if I'm authorized to share the code. :(